# What will happen if i replace ubuntu system HDD to other computer? From pc to notebook for example

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

What will happen if I move ubuntu system HDD to another computer. From pc to notebook for example. Will it work out of the box?

Comment: "Will it work out of the box?" Remove all 3rd party drivers and it most likely will work. I've done this a few times. Mind you: a hdd for pc might be larger than what the notebook can handle. A notebook tends to need a 2.5" and a PC tends to have 3.5".

Answer (score 2):

Provided the hardware is close enough it should work fine. That being said you can't run a 64-bit version on a 32 bit CPU. You may also have issues with your graphics card and have to reconfigure X. Granted this is based on personal experience. Your mileage may vary.